# What's the correct preposition for the word "rant"?

Tags: word-choice

When I want to say "Stop ranting on him!", is this grammatically correct?

I am confused about which preposition I should use with the word "rant/ranting"

Comment: No one preposition always goes with *rant*. What is your intended meaning, or what dictionary have you used to try to answer this?

Comment: "About" is the usual usage.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin  I wanted to use it like "nagging". For example, "She nags me about sth" but if I want to change "nag" to "rant", how can I do it?

Comment: I’d say you can rant *about* someone/something, rant *to* someone about something, rant *at* someone.

Comment: You are obviously learning English, so you are on the wrong site. You need English Language Learners.

Comment: *Nagging* and *ranting* are orthagonal concepts. You can do both at the same time, but they are not synonyms and neither one entails the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Stop ranting at him!**

*Rant* is usually an intransitive verb. It can be paired with several prepositional phrases to provide information about the ranting.

If you want to signal the target of the rant, or the person hearing it, consider *[at](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at)*:

> —used as a function word to indicate the goal of an indicated or implied action or motion

For example, the Merriam Webster thesaurus gives this collocation definition and example for *rant (at)*:

> to criticize (someone) severely or angrily especially for personal failings
>
> Grandmother **ranted at** us for skipping the family holiday gathering in favor of a ski trip

Answer (score 1):

Merriam Webster considers *rant* to be an intransitive verb.

[Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rant)

To describe the **cause** of the rant *(object of annoyance)*, use the preposition *about* .  Example:

*"Stop ranting about him."*